# Azure portal Template Deployment not supporting Keyvault references

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I have a set of resources and want to deploy them using **Template Deployment** feature in Azure portal. In my parameters file, I have few references to parameters in Key Vault as mentioned [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/keyvault-support-for-arm-templates/). When deploying the template in Azure portal (clicking on **Deploy a custom template**) and supplying these values, the portal still asks for these parameters explicitly which I definitely cannot provide in plain text.

When using the same resources.json and parameters.json file in powershell, it works fine.Is the feature of KeyVault references currently not supported in Template Deployment done through portal ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the case, but you can workaround that by wrapping you template with another template and that template will "get" the reference and pass it to the actual template.

reference: https://github.com/4c74356b41/bbbb-is-the-word/blob/master/_arm/parent.json#L151

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am doing exactly the same thing. But still, when I go to the last step which says "Edit parameters", these values are blank (and neither their reference, nor their actual values are present there) and I need to provide these values there (probably in plain text). But that just removes the benefit of KeyVault overall.

Comment: you are not doing the same thing if you have this error. you need to wrap your template with another template and use parent template to input parameters. or just use cli\powershell\SDK to deploy